# Is there any way to lock on a band or channel in code like what network signal guru app do?

Tags: android

In my project I need to lock the mobile network on an arfcn(channel) and band and I need to do it in my app automatically not manual, Network Signal Guru do it by root phones , is there any code or something to help me ?

Comment: You cannot access/modify any kind of band or channel related staff on non-rooted android. you must need root access to change these data.

Comment: @JineshChhichhiya I Know that , I need a code to do that in rooted phones.